# Hide standard toolchains from C/C++ project wizard

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-cdt

Our team is developing a custom toolchain. We want to build it in to Eclipse CDT. We don't want to see an excess element in a final product.

Is it possible to hide/disable/delete standard toolchains in C/C++ Project Wizard?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FW3oL.png)

Previously, I hid a default Debug Configurations using org.eclipse.ui.activities extension point. This time it doesn't help we. I tried to remove CrossGCC plugin but a Unistall... button in Install Software is greyed out.

I use Eclipse Luna RCP (4.4.2) for plugin development.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with this part of CDT, but after doing a bit of code browsing, it seems like the extension points `org.eclipse.cdt.core.templates` and `org.eclipse.cdt.core.templateAssociations` may be relevant.

See how e.g. the current CDT code [uses these extension points](http://git.eclipse.org/c/cdt/org.eclipse.cdt.git/tree/build/org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.gnu.ui/plugin.xml#n4017) to associate a set of toolchains with a project template. If your plugins define their own project template(s), perhaps you could do something similar to control the list of associated toolchains?

Comment: It is a good idea, although I still need to hide the rest toolchains. So I need to find their id.